# How to pass value to ON CONFLICT clause that's not a column?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.6

Basically, I'm trying to do multiple inserts in a single command in postgresql, where my `ON CONFLICT` has a per-insert parameter.

Here is the query (formatted for `psycopg2`):

```
INSERT INTO
    web_pages
    (url, starturl, netloc, distance, is_text, 
     priority, type, addtime, state)
VALUES
    (%(url)s, %(starturl)s, %(netloc)s, %(distance)s, %(is_text)s, 
      %(priority)s, %(type)s, %(addtime)s, %(state)s)
ON CONFLICT (url) DO
    UPDATE
        SET
            state           = EXCLUDED.state,
            starturl        = EXCLUDED.starturl,
            netloc          = EXCLUDED.netloc,
            is_text         = EXCLUDED.is_text,
            distance        = LEAST(EXCLUDED.distance, web_pages.distance),
            priority        = GREATEST(EXCLUDED.priority, web_pages.priority),
            addtime         = LEAST(EXCLUDED.addtime, web_pages.addtime)
        WHERE
        (
                web_pages.ignoreuntiltime < %(ignoreuntiltime)s
            AND
                web_pages.url = EXCLUDED.url
            AND
                (web_pages.state = 'complete' OR web_pages.state = 'error')
        )
    ;
```

I want to be able to pass multiple `VALUES` tuples, but `%(ignoreuntiltime)s` can vary per value-tuple.

Is there any way I can specify it as a additional parameter in the `values` tuple, or similar, for each row?

What I want is kind of:

```
INSERT INTO
    web_pages
    (url, starturl, netloc, distance, is_text, 
     priority, type, addtime, state, not_a_column)
VALUES
    (%(url)s, %(starturl)s, %(netloc)s, %(distance)s, %(is_text)s, 
     %(priority)s, %(type)s, %(addtime)s, %(state)s, %(ignoreuntiltime)s)
    ....(more value tuples here)....
ON CONFLICT (url) DO
    UPDATE
        SET
            state           = EXCLUDED.state,
            starturl        = EXCLUDED.starturl,
            netloc          = EXCLUDED.netloc,
            is_text         = EXCLUDED.is_text,
            distance        = LEAST(EXCLUDED.distance, web_pages.distance),
            priority        = GREATEST(EXCLUDED.priority, web_pages.priority),
            addtime         = LEAST(EXCLUDED.addtime, web_pages.addtime)
        WHERE
        (
                web_pages.ignoreuntiltime < EXCLUDED.not_a_column
            AND
                web_pages.url = EXCLUDED.url
            AND
                (web_pages.state = 'complete' OR web_pages.state = 'error')
        )
    ;
```

Comment: It would make your question ***much*** more useful if you provided an example without irrelevant ballast. We don't need all those columns and orthogonal `WHERE` conditions to deal with the interesting core of the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I've had issues where when I simplify the query, I get answers that no longer work in the actual situation where I actually have the issue.

Comment: Yes, the art is to simplify, but include everything that's relevant. Can be tricky, granted.

Answer (score 5):

### Not possible, because

There is currently no direct way in Postgres **9.6**, because:

- In the `UPDATE`, only the special `EXCLUDED` row is visible (in addition to the updated row). There is no `FROM` clause allowed to join in additional tables.
- The `EXCLUDED` row is exactly the state of the would-be inserted row that was rejected by conflict. Exactly the columns of the table to be inserted into. Nothing more.

So there is no room for any additional columns not mentioned in the `INSERT` in the `UPDATE` branch of the UPSERT. Future version may allow more. Various additions have been discussed, but not yet implemented. [It's a complex matter.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT)

### Clean workaround

I suggest this workaround using CTEs.

1. Provide rows with all columns you need in a free-standing `VALUES` expression. (CTE `data` in below example.)
2. Run `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`, but do *not* actually update any rows (`WHERE FALSE`). The desired side effect: excluded rows are locked anyway to make it ***safe for concurrent use***.
   With just `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`, conflicting rows are not locked and fair game for concurrent transactions. ***If*** there cannot be concurrent writes to the same rows of the same table, use this cheaper variant.
3. Run a separate `UPDATE` as part of the ***same command***, where you can use *all* columns from the CTE `data` - and join in arbitrary additional tables, too, if needed.

Demo table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (tbl_id int PRIMARY KEY, note text);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
   (1, 'old1')
 , (2, 'old2');
```

Demo query:

```
WITH data (tbl_id, note) AS (
   VALUES
      (int '1', text 'update')   -- explicit type declarations for free standing VALUES
    , (2, 'no update')           -- going to exclude row in WHERE of UPDATE
    , (3, 'insert')              -- not going to INSERT the "note"
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl AS t (tbl_id) -- "note" not inserted
   SELECT tbl_id FROM data
   ON     CONFLICT (tbl_id) DO UPDATE
   SET    note = NULL
   WHERE  FALSE                  -- never executed, but locks row.
   RETURNING t.tbl_id
   )
UPDATE tbl t
SET    note = d.note             -- now we can!
FROM   data d
LEFT   JOIN ins i USING (tbl_id)
WHERE  i.tbl_id IS NULL
AND    t.tbl_id = d.tbl_id
AND    d.note <> 'no update';    -- just to demonstrate use in WHERE
```

Result:

```
TABLE tbl ORDER BY tbl_id;
```

> ```
>  tbl_id |  note
> --------+--------
>       1 | update   -- updated
>       2 | old2     -- not updated because of WHERE in UPDATE
>       3 |          -- inserted without "note"
> ```

Related:

- [How to include excluded rows in RETURNING from INSERT … ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949877/how-to-include-excluded-rows-in-returning-from-insert-on-conflict/35953488#35953488)

Comment: FWIW, I wound up just implementing it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @FakeName: Possible concurrency issues apply for functions in the same way. If race conditions are possible, use `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE ... WHERE  FALSE` to lock excluded rows. Be that in a single command with CTEs as demonstrated, or in a function (or any transaction) with separate consecutive commands.

Comment: How would there be concurrency issues? Assuming this is within a transaction with a `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, I'd think it'd be safe in all cases (the function has no `COMMIT`s internally)

Comment: @FakeName: There should be no concurrency issues with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, which you only just mentioned now. The Postgres default isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` and *substantially* cheaper, especially for use cases with concurrency. My answer and comments naturally assume the default. `COMMIT` is not possible in Postgres functions.

Comment: Ah, I see. I tend to switch to `SERIALIZABLE` because it exposes any software issues on my part more readily. Maybe time to re-evaluate that.